# grouped bar chart in pyplot not rendering

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Simple problem I'm sure, but after doing tons of hunting around I cant find any reason this shouldn't be working. While trying to plot a grouped bar chart of 2010 and 2014 population data side by side, only 2014 is visible and the side for 2010 is blank. What is my mistake here?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

myFrame = pd.read_csv('top12cities.csv', sep = ',', engine = 'python')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ind = np.arange(len(myFrame['City']))
width = .35
p1 = plt.bar(ind, myFrame['2014 estimate'], width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind + .35, myFrame['2010 Census'], width, color='y')
plt.legend([p1[0],p2[0]], ['2014', '2010'], loc = 'best')
plt.xticks(ind + width /2,myFrame['City'],rotation = 90)
plt.xlabel("Name")
plt.ylabel('population')
plt.savefig('popbar.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Because nobody can run this code, just anything can be the reason. Please read and understand [mcve]. Then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code ran fine on my machine with a test csv with the schema

> City,2010 Census,2014 estimate
>   New York, 34, 123
>   L.A., 14, 89
>   San Fran, 14, 30

It may be worth trying to check if your csv file has issues of some kind, like non-numeric entries in the problematic column. I got this:
[image: Test image]

Comment: That was it. The data had a string in there, thanks!